# Which period is this game map supposed to represent?

Tags: identification, maps

I have gotten my hands on a handmade Diplomacy variant, however for the life of me I can't figure out which period it is supposed to represent. Of course the author had to take liberties when designing the map, but I would just like to know which generic period we're talking about.

[image: A map showing most of Europe. Yellow controls London, York, and Bordeau; Blue controls Rouen, Paris, and Dauphine; Brown controls Saxony, Brandenburg, and Bavaria, Light Brown controls Denmark, Norway, and Sweden; Orange controls Vilnius, Krakow, and Kiev; Green controls Budapest, Croatia, and Transylvania; Red controls Bulgaria (and likely other portions outside the image border); Dark Green's control in the Iberian peninsula is visible but the names are not, but don't include Aragon or Navarra. All other divisions on the map are uncolored.]

From the research I have done so far I *think* it's a late medieval period, but I am far from sure, to be honest.

Comment: I don't think it represents any particular period. It includes the papal states, which would suggest the middle ages but Wales appears to occupy a large chunk of western England and Cornwall, which wasn't the case during any part of the middle ages - It's a game-balanced map not a historic one.

Comment: @SteveBird Yeah, figured as much when I said 'had to take liberty', guess I just underestimated how much liberty :) Oh well, the 1500 ± 200 is the kind of answer I was looking for, even though I don't like it much xD .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  questions based on fantasy/games are not History.

Comment: @TheHonRose : The question is not an in-universe question about a fantasy map. The question was what kind of real historical period this drawing most closely resembles.

Comment: I like this question for its puzzle nature and welcome it here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### 1400

A notable feature of this map is the English possession of Western France, which means that it's no later than 1453, when France took Bordeaux. Since in the Diplomacy game you color only the ownership of "supply centers" (represented by circles on the map, the larger industrial/population centres) this is consistent with France owning Paris, Rouen and Dauphine and the rest of the provinces being "unimportant" - the same with Wales, as it's not a "supply center" then it cannot have an owner and it being without color does not imply Wales being independent from England.

Another feature is an unified Denmark, Sweden and Norway, which happened from 1397 as Kalmar Union.

This year is also consistent with a Castile without Aragon, possession of Kiev by Poland-Lithuania and Bulgaria owned by Ottomans.

The only liberty taken seems to be a bit overly unified Germany-Brandenburg.

Comment: @KillingTime the game map does *not* show Wales controlling anything, and it does not show York and Lancaster being as distinct political regions. As per Diplomacy rules, this map shows a political entity controlling London,York and Bordeaux; an independent political entity controlling Scotland, and the rest of regions there are just geographical - they cannot be "controlled", they're just used for unit movement.

Comment: Not sure if you're claiming this is a historic map or not. You assert that this represents Europe in 1400 and then state that the region boundaries are "per Diplomacy rules...". Clearly the divisions within Wales and England do not show any historically accurate boundaries for 1400.

Comment: @SteveBird the region boundaries represent a split of the whole map for "movement purposes" in roughly equally sized geographical (not political) regions. The political structure, on the other hand, is represented only by the coloring (or not) of the regions with circles in them; this map indicates that at this point  Rouen, Paris and Dauphine are owned by one entity, Bordeaux, London and York are owned by another entity; Flanders and Scotland are independent from both, and doesn't say anything whatsoever about ownership/control of other regions w/o the circles e.g. Gascony, Wales, etc.

Comment: Perhaps a bit earlier than 1400: the Hapsburgs gained Tyrol in 1369.

Comment: @Drux in this map Tyrol is not a SC, so there's no information about who has or hasn't gained Tyrol. However, it cannot be ~1369 because then Denmark/Sweden/Norway aren't unified.

Answer (score 16):

This map is not historically accurate.

For example there is an entity called ["Prussia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussia) and an entity called ["Novgorod"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novgorod_Republic), while in reality they never existed at the same time.

It's a mixture of maybe 1500ish plus minus 200 years and a *lot* of artistic freedom.

Comment: As well as Budapest. Buda and Pest united in the 19th century.

Comment: Uh That is incorrect. Prussia is there for the Baltic region Prussia, not the German state Prussia, headed by House of Hohenzollern

Comment: As you can see, Brandenburg is displayed as a free entity when in fact Hohenzollerns of Prussia came from Brandenburg

Comment: Thank you, I figured that some artistic freedom was taken, but I guess I was just underestimating how much :) Was expecting it more to be some year plus minus 50 years, but oh well, still that last line gives me the kind of estimate I needed, so thanks!

Comment: The map does not show an *entity* called Prussia, but the region was named so for a thousand years and certainly overlaps many centuries where Novgorod was the dominant city of the region drawn there.

Comment: I don't believe France has *ever* been divided up that way either. The only time I can think of that England looked anything like that was during the 800's.

Comment: Looks like someone was having fun with their imaginary Europe again.

Comment: @NSNoob : *"Brandenburg is displayed as a free entity"* - no, it isn't. In many variant of the the board game, only supply centers are colored.

Comment: Another point: Finland is under the control of Novgorod. Anything close to that did not happen until the 18th century, and then only for a brief time. Finland was only under permanent Russian control from the Napoleon wars until the end of WWI. From the thirteenth century to 1809, it was part of Sweden.

Comment: Saxony also seems to be located quite a bit wrong

Comment: @andejons it doesn't display Finland as under the control of Novgorod - it chooses to group all this land as a single geographical region, and labels it according to the largest population center, which was Novgorod even in e.g. 12th century.

Comment: @Peteris: Most other regions follow actual borders, at least roughly. From what I can tell, there would have been no difference in game play if Finland was grouped with the rest of Sweden. If we are not to evaluate the map as reflecting actual political reality, the original question makes no sense at all.